# In react.js, a piece of css style that is mysteriously applied to a component; How to find how it is applied, by the help of chrome developer mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Material React Table; In the table, 2 columns are almost the same;

They only differ in:

column A has filterVariant: 'text';

column B has filterVariant: 'select';

So the filter input in column A is a text field for you to type in texts;
the filter input in column B is a select dropdown for you to open the dropdown and click the option you want to select;

However, the two filters are a bit different in UI:
image:

see the gap? the underline of the filter are not at the same level; the second one is a bit higher;

[image]

column B's filter looks more narrow in height;

In Browser developer mode, on inspection,

I found that in column A's filter:

```
.css-12pkzps-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input
{
  font: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  color: currentColor;
  padding: 4px 0 5px;  // this is the key
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background: none;
  height: 1.4375em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: mui-auto-fill-cancel;
  animation-name: mui-auto-fill-cancel;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10ms;
  animation-duration: 10ms;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

It has `padding: 4px 0 5px;`

And I found that in column B's filter:

```
.css-y3y8ml-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input.MuiSelect-select
{
  display: grid;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.75rem !important; // this is causing the filter to look thinner!! 
}

.css-y3y8ml-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input
{
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  color: currentColor;
  padding: 4px 0 5px;  // this line is sriked through and greyed out; 
  ...
}
```

It has the same `padding: 4px 0 5px;` at first, but then it is over-written by `padding: 0 0.75rem !important;` above.

However, in the react.js code where the table and the columns are defined, there is no code that applies the `padding: 0 0.75rem !important;` style.

How can I debug this and find out where this mysterious `padding: 0 0.75rem !important;` is from?